# undefined reference to methods of class

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries

I have a test app and static library. The problem undefined reference to methods of class Log, but I can't find error in a code.

Logs of complie:

```
g++ -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include log.cpp -o log.o
ar rc libDeka.a log.o
g++ -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include -L . -lDeka main.o -o test.exe
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Log::Get()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `Log::Print(char const*, ...)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `Log::Get()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `Log::~Log()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Makefile

```
CC=g++
LINK=g++

LIBARIES=-lDeka

CFLAGS= -c -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include
LINKFLAGS= -O0 -std=c++14 -Wall -I ../SDL_DekaLib/include -L . $(LIBARIES)

all: main.o libDeka.a
    $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o -o test.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o main.o

libDeka.a: log.o
    ar rc libDeka.a log.o

log.o: log.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) log.cpp -o log.o

clean:
    del *.o
    del *.exe
    del *.a
```

log.h

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstdarg>

class Log
    {
    public:
        Log();
        ~Log();

        static Log* Get();
        void Print(const char* message, ...);
        void Debug(const char* message, ...);
        void Error(const char* message, ...);
    private:
        static Log* _instance;
        FILE* _file;

        void _print(const char* lvltext, const char* message);
        void _init();
        void _close();
    };
```

log.cpp - without realisation

```
#include "log.h"

Log* Log::_instance = nullptr;

void Log::_init()
    {
        ...
    }
void Log::_close()
    {
        ...
    }
Log::Log() : _file(nullptr)
    {
        _init();
    }
Log::~Log()
    {
        _close();
        _instance = nullptr;
    }
Log* Log::Get()
    {
        if(!Log::_instance)
            Log::_instance = new Log();

        return Log::_instance;
    }
void Log::Print(const char* message, ...)
    {
        ...
    }
void Log::Debug(const char* message, ...)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG

        ...

#endif // DEBUG
    }
void Log::Error(const char* message, ...)
    {
        ...
    }

    void Log::_print(const char* lvltext, const char* message)
    {
        ...
    }
```

main.cpp

```
#include "log.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Log::Get()->Print("Test %d", 50);

    delete Log::Get();
    return 0;
}
```

Just in case all files here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zczlmotz56rspk/LogError.zip?dl=0)

Comment: 1.) Does the `libDeka.a` actually contain the functions? 2.) Any chance that there's another `libDeka.a` file floating around on your machine and g++ accidentally picks up the wrong one?

Comment: 1) libDeka definitely has functions
2) libDeka.a is only one file in folder and desen't exist in any path in PATH value

Comment: Does it work with `ar rcs` instead of just `ar rc`?

Comment: No changes with `ar rcs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

> -l library
>   ...
>   It makes a difference where in the command you write this option; the linker searches and processes libraries and object files in the order they are specified. Thus, ‘foo.o -lz bar.o’ searches library ‘z’ after file foo.o but before bar.o. If bar.o refers to functions in ‘z’, those functions may not be loaded.

Means you need to place `main.o` before `-lDeka`. Change the order in your link directive:

> $(LINK) $(LINKFLAGS) main.o -o test.exe

change it so that `main.o` appears before `-lDeka`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `log.o` to the main target:

```
all: main.o libDeka.a log.o
```

Comment: I suppose the OP wants to resolve the references via the `libDeka` library and not add everything from the library manually.

Comment: @Christian Hackl What i must do?

Comment: @lorro For example, SDL library doesn't need to include object files, What i must do to something also in SDL

Answer (score 0):

Is the third row in your makefile `LIBARIES=-lDeka` correct?  Shouldn't it be `LIBRARIES=-lDeka`?

Comment: I'm bad in english. It's problem, but the main issue had resolved.